# Antiderivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Prove or disprove that $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{for $x \neq 0$} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

has an antiderivative in $\mathbb{R}$.

This function satisfies the Darboux's property, but how to say definitely that admits an antiderivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have an antiderivative. Let$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{ if $x \neq 0$} \\0 & \text{ if $x=0$.}\end{cases}$$Then $g$ *has* an antiderivative. So, if $f$ had one, $f-g$ would have an antiderivative too. But $f-g$ doesn't satisfy the Darboux property.

In order to see why $g$ has an antiderivative, consider the function$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$Then$$h'(x)=\begin{cases}2x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)+\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$But the function$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}2x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$is continuous and therefore has an antiderivative. Therefore, $g$ has an antiderivative too.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima The question is not about being integrable. It's about having an antiderivative.

Comment: It means that it doesn't satisfy the intermediate value property.

Comment: It is the first time i hear Darboux property. In french, they don't use this.

Comment: Why $f-g$ should have necessarly an antiderivative?

Comment: How can i be sure that if two functions $t(x)$ and $u(x)$ have an antiderivative, then $t(x)+u(x)$ has an antiderivative?

Comment: Because if $T'=t$ and $U'=u$, then $(T+U)'=T'+U'=t+u$.